# responsive group of images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to make a group of images-list page using bootstrap but I can't make it responsive on other resolutions, The images moves left and the entire style of the arrangement will break.

```
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="source-path">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="source-path">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="source-path">
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-responsive" src="source-path">
  </div>
<div>
```

in this one ^ The images appears in 1-row and not sided to each other, And when I use `style="float: left;"` it works but not responsive as I wished, Is there a better way to make a better album{images-list} using bootstrap?

Comment: Make all images in one row div @J. 4RK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are *responsive*.
In the sense that they do scale down depending on parent size.
Here is how  `.img-responsive` is defined in Bootstrap 3:

```
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Please note, as [Sreemat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5488855/sreemat) well pointed out,  you do not need to wrap the images in `<div>`s since they already have `display:block`.

The problem is most people, when they say `responsive` they also expect it to grow in size according to the parent's width, which ***`.img-responsive` does not do***, as doing that has the potential of making small images look *really* bad.

But if that's your desired behavior, add this to your CSS:

```
.img-responsive {
  min-width: 100%:
}
```